# for loop fails to do its job when file has 2 or more lines?

Tags: python

So I have this snippet:

I'm opening 2 files and storing their lines into 2 separate lists.
then creating a new list that filters out matching lines.

So when both files have just the 1 line, and both lines are matching. then the 1st list length == 1, and the 2nd list length == 0 and this is correct.
But when both files have 2 or more matching lines then it completely fails and doesn't filter properly coz it then says the 1st list length == 2 and the 2nd list length also == 2 when the 2nd list should == 0 as the lines are matching.

I feel silly coming to stack overflow to resolve this when it seems so minor and I've managed to solve a lot harder things but I've been working on this for almost 2hrs now and its driving me crazy.

My guess is I'm overlooking something so simple so if you see what that is then please point it out. thanks.

file 1 contents with 1 line:

```
loaded_sound,sfx/levels/zombie/maps/asylum/switch/gen_arc/gen_arc_loop.wav
```

file 2 contents with 1 line:

```
loaded_sound,sfx/levels/zombie/maps/asylum/switch/gen_arc/gen_arc_loop.wav
```

this code snippet will return length 1 and length 0. which is correct.

but with this:

file 1 contents with 2 lines:

```
loaded_sound,sfx/levels/nazi_zombie_sumpf/amb_fire/small/small_00.wav
loaded_sound,sfx/levels/nazi_zombie_sumpf/amb_fire/small/small_01.wav
```

file 2 contents with 2 lines:

```
loaded_sound,sfx/levels/nazi_zombie_sumpf/amb_fire/small/small_00.wav
loaded_sound,sfx/levels/nazi_zombie_sumpf/amb_fire/small/small_01.wav
```

this code snippet will return length 2 and length 2. which is incorrect as the lines are matching.

```py
f1 = join(f"{WAW_ROOT_DIR}/zone_source/english/assetlist/{CURRENT_SELECTED_MOD}.csv")
with open(f1, 'r') as assetList:
    assetList_text = [i.strip() for i in assetList]

# this loaded_sounds list will have 2 lines in it.
loaded_sounds = [i.strip() for i in assetList_text if i.startswith("loaded_sound")]
# length = 2
logging.info(f"old loaded sounds: {len(loaded_sounds)}")

path_ = join(f"{WAW_ROOT_DIR}/zone_source/english/assetlist/{CURRENT_SELECTED_MOD}_ignore_sound.csv")
if exists(path_) and isfile(path_):
    with open(path_, 'r') as file:
        # this list also has 2 lines in it (2 matching lines as the list above)
        ignored_sounds_file = [i.strip() for i in file]

    # now what im doing here is creating a new list where i only add items from the 1st list that arent in the 2nd list.
    # this works when both files have 1 matching line.
    # but when i have 2 or more matching lines it fails to do its job and adds both items from 1st list to 2nd list when it shouldnt be adding any at all as theyre matching lines.

    loadedSounds = []
    for i in ignored_sounds_file:
        if i in loaded_sounds:
            for j in loaded_sounds:
                if j != i and j not in loadedSounds:
                    loadedSounds.append(j)
     print("end")

     logging.info(f"new loaded sounds: {len(loadedSounds)}")
else:
    print("no ignore file detected")
return
```

Comment: Use `result = set(first_list) - set(second_list)`. You don't need to write any loops.

Comment: You're appending a line if it's different from any line in the other file. You need to check if it doesn't match *all* the lines in the other file.

Comment: @Barmar ty sir this:
result = set(first_list) - set(second_list)
appears to be returning the correct results.

p.s i will take a look at amending my code snippet now after reading your 2nd comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Barmer solved this issue.
"result = set(first_list) - set(second_list)"

Comment: "you can accept your own answer in 2 days".. fail.

Comment: Barmer's fault for answering in a comment.